# Start two activeMQ brokers with maven

Tags: java, maven, activemq-classic

I have maven project with activeMQ config xml only for starting broker with: mvn activemq:run. The problem is, that I need to have 2 instances started (2 masters connected in broker net), is there any way of doing this. Ofcouse, I can expose it in java code, like:
Broker b1 = ...  Broker b2 = ....  config and start them.(but then I would not have maven) I need this for integration tests, they are not automate, it's pretty hard to start 2 brokers manualy, run tests, if something wrong message stuck and there are failures, hart to understand is it test failure or just environment problem. Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, but if launching and tearing down your brokers could be done with a custom plugin using the Java code you already know,  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/ may help you with running the tests between the launch and teardown of the broker.

If not, there may be some good clues in the source code of that plugin for how it could be done.

Comment: Thank you, going to try this.